# Confusion for @RequestMapping solving one value and a list values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have created a class called `User`, and I want to test `@RequestMapping` with POST and GET. I created 2 methods, one is for one object, and the other one is for a list of Objects. However, when I test GET on the return one object method which only allowed POST, it turns value back, and values are a list of objects. So why does it cause?

```
@RestController
public class WebController {
 @PostMapping(name="/getUser123")
    public User getUser(){
        User user=new User();
        user.setName("mint");
        user.setAge(19);
        user.setPass("123456");
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(name="/changeWholeName")
    public List<User> changeWholeName(){
        List<User> users =new ArrayList<User>();
        User user1=new User();
        user1.setName("mint1");
        user1.setAge(19);
        user1.setPass("123456");
        users.add(user1);
        User user2=new User();
        user2.setName("mint3");
        user2.setAge(192);
        user2.setPass("1234516");
        users.add(user2);
        return users;
    }
}
```

Use GET to test the first method,`GET localhost:8080/getUser`, and it goes into the second method, return a list of values. Why and how to solve this? Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is `Assign a name to this mapping.`
You should change `name` to `value`

```
@PostMapping(value="/getUser123")
    public User getUser(){
        User user=new User();
        user.setName("mint");
        user.setAge(19);
        user.setPass("123456");
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/changeWholeName")
    public List<User> changeWholeName(){
        List<User> users =new ArrayList<User>();
        User user1=new User();
        user1.setName("mint1");
        user1.setAge(19);
        user1.setPass("123456");
        users.add(user1);
        User user2=new User();
        user2.setName("mint3");
        user2.setAge(192);
        user2.setPass("1234516");
        users.add(user2);
        return users;
    }
```

**For more detail:**

You can read this page to get more detail about `name` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromMappingName-java.lang.String-.

I assume that your `@Controller` class is handing request to `localhost:8080/getUser` with default method is `GET`. Therefore, it will call `changeWholeName()` because the method handles `GET` request. Because you used name instead of value, Spring understands your code like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getUser")
public UserController {
@RequestMapping(value="", name="/changeWholeName") //Handle HTTP GET to /getUser
    public List<User> changeWholeName(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works well! But I have another question, what the name used for? If it only used to identify a method for men, why do I use GET localhost:8080/getUser123 works and it returns a list of values, not an exception? Thanks!

Comment: Because the explanation is too long, I added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your adding answer, I looked into the reference you mentioned, and I thought it isn't suitable for my code   :(   So I put the whole paragraph of codes on and could you see it again? Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok, just do it.

Comment: Could you post your whole project code on somewhere like github?

Comment: Yes,and I have already push it here:https://github.com/Timzhouyes/hello

Comment: You can try to send GET request to `localhost:8080/abcxyz`. It works :)))
Because if you didn't specify any mapping, Spring Boot will auto config to handle with path `/*`

Comment: Thanks!! So that is the reason for my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to do, please be more precise.

But first of all your POST method `getUser` returns a User and therefore should be annotated with `@GetMapping("/getUser123")` or `@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser123", method = RequestMethod.GET)` which is the same. You see that you should define the HTTP method to be used when using `@RequestMapping`.

And you should name your methods according to what they do, otherwise it causes confusion.

You can read more about Spring's Controller Annotations [here](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-getmapping-postmapping-putmapping-deletemapping-patchmapping.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I use GET to test the first method, it returns a list of Users, and doesn't return an Exception.I use a breakpoint to see it , and it shows the program goes into the second method, which returns a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods return some data, then both are should be accessed using GET request.

> You can Access this method by http://localhost:8080/getUser123

```
    @GetMapping(value="/getUser123")
    public User getUser(){
        User user=new User();
        user.setName("mint");
        user.setAge(19);
        user.setPass("123456");
        return user;
    }
```

> You can Access this method by http://localhost:8080/changeWholeName

```
    @GetMapping(value="/changeWholeName")
    public List<User> changeWholeName(){
        List<User> users =new ArrayList<User>();
        User user1=new User();
        user1.setName("mint1");
        user1.setAge(19);
        user1.setPass("123456");
        users.add(user1);
        User user2=new User();
        user2.setName("mint3");
        user2.setAge(192);
        user2.setPass("1234516");
        users.add(user2);
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the first "/getUser123" with POST should return 405 error , but in my test, it returns the value if "/changeWholename", so that's why I confused

Comment: can you share your request URL?